# how do you change into another directory in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

how do change directory 'cd' into another directory in a shell script

i notice that when i run the shell script, it doesnt switch directories.

Can anyone help please

```
sudo yum update
sudo dnf groupinstall 'development tools'
sudo dnf -y install bzip2 wget gcc gcc-c++ gmp-devel mpfr-devel libmpc-devel make
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.2.0/gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz
tar -xvf gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz
cd gcc-10.2.0
./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
```

Comment: The subshell which runs the script does change directory, but that doesn't affect the parent shell from which you ran it.

Comment: how about `cd gcc-10.2.0  &&  ./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib`